# How can I make a binary executable a command?

Tags: shell, command-line

I have a binary file as part of the software that I developed. How can I make it an actual command in the command line? For example, if my executable is called `mysoftware`, how can I let a user do `mysoftware <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>` instead of `./mysoftware <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>` which is kind of clunky.

Comment: add the location to the `PATH` variable

Comment: ...or move the binary to a folder contained in the `PATH` variable :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable will need to be in the user's PATH somewhere. `/usr/bin` and `/bin` are two common places, but there are others.

You can do `$ echo $PATH` to see what directories (for you) are in your PATH, then maybe add a command in your Makefile (common practice is `make install`) to have it copy the executable to that location.